# dynamic autocomplete in mui next js

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js13

is autocomplete in mui can dynamic it
i use
const {
fields: BenchMarkFields,
append: BenchMarkAppend,
remove: BenchMarkRemove,
} = useFieldArray({
control,
name: "BenchMark",
});
like this to create autocomplete array and if user click on create autocomplete it will appear initial data and if the data was set it on save button it will save it to database and if user go to page again it will get autocomplete on database and still click to create new autocomplete how can i fix it ?

```
{BenchMarkFields.map((fields, i: number) => (
                <Grid
                  key={fields.id}
                  container
                  spacing={2}
                  sx={{ marginTop: "20px" }}
                >
                  <Grid item xs={10}>
                    <Controller
                      key={i}
                      name={`BenchMark.${i}.rule`}
                      control={control}
                      rules={{ required: true }}
                      render={({ field }) => (
                        <Autocomplete
                          fullWidth
                          color="success"
                          options={departments}
                          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
                          onChange={(e, newValue) => {
                            field.onChange(newValue?.label);
                            handleChange(newValue, i);
                          }}
                          renderInput={(params) => (
                            <TextField
                              {...params}
                              label="กรม สธร."
                              error={!isEmpty(errors.BenchMark?.[i]?.rule)}
                            />
                          )}
                          isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) =>
                            option.value === value?.value &&
                            option.label === value?.label
                          }
                        />
                      )}
                    />
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={1}>
                    <TextField
                      {...register(`BenchMark.${i}.weight` as const, {
                        required: true,
                        valueAsNumber: true,
                      })}
                      type="number"
                      InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 0 } }}
                      variant="outlined"
                      label="ค่าน้ำหนัก"
                      error={!isEmpty(errors.BenchMark?.[i]?.weight)}
                      helperText={
                        !isEmpty(errors.BenchMark?.[i]?.weight)
                          ? "กรุณาระบุ ค่าน้ำหนัก"
                          : undefined
                      }
                    />
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={11}>
                    <Controller
                      key={i}
                      name={`BenchMark.${i}.detail`}
                      control={control}
                      rules={{ required: true }}
                      render={({ field }) => (
                        <Autocomplete
                          fullWidth
                          color="success"
                          options={departmentOptions}
                          onChange={(e, newValue) => {
                            field.onChange(newValue?.label);
                            handleSub(newValue, i);
                          }}
                          renderInput={(params) => (
                            <TextField
                              {...params}
                              label="เกณท์"
                              error={!isEmpty(errors.BenchMark?.[i]?.detail)}
                            />
                          )}
                        />
                      )}
                    />
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item xs={1}>
                    <Box
                      sx={{ mt: 2, cursor: "pointer", textAlign: "center" }}
                      onClick={() => _deleteBenchMark(i)}
                    >
                      <DeleteIcon />
                    </Box>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
              ))}
```

if it textfield it work but autocomplete in mui not get data when i get it from db

json data like this

[{"rule":"ส่งกำลังบำรุง","detail":"ความปลอดภัย","weight":2,"id":"b3e270bf-a0db-4ae7-b2b2-9a4eac0906cf","jmdmpAcceptId":38}]

i try in textfield is work but autocomplete is not work when i get it from api